# Issue with combobox autocomplete

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to incorporate three comboboxes into a functional GUI which consist of textboxes,  numericupdown controls and now comboboxes.
On those form I have navigation with keyboard (me.selectnextcontrol) with keys up and down.
What happens?
When I step in those GUI for first time everything work OK and I can move up/down with keyboard as expected.

Problem becomes when I edit a combobox which is in the midle of my gui and is set like this:

```
    mycombo.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend
    mycombo.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
    mycombo.AutoCompleteCustomSource = myAutoCompleteStringCollection
```

Problem is that when I come back to those combobox my navigation loop don't get keypress (up or down keys) anymore because combobox takes them for itselfs purpose (change index).

I try with `mycombo.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource` after combobox_Leave but that turns off autocomplete what is not wanted.

Question is:
Is here possible to set described combobox after usage in mode like it was at the beginning of program, when it was not edited, so I can navigate with keyboard through such comboboxes at initial way but that autosuggest option remain enabled if I need to edit it again.

EDITED:
Here is simple example which shows a problem:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim tb As New TextBox
    Dim cbb As New ComboBox
    Dim tbb As New TextBox
    Dim b1 As New Button
    Dim b2 As New Button

    With Me
        .KeyPreview = True
        .Size = New Size(350, 200)
        With .Controls
            .Add(tb)
            With tb
                .TabIndex = 0
                .Location = New Point(95, 20)
                .Text = "This is"
            End With
            .Add(cbb)
            With cbb
                .TabIndex = 1
                .Items.AddRange(New String() {"alabama", "africa", "australia", "grenland"})
                .Location = New Point(95, 50)
                .Text = "an Example"
                .DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown
                .AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend
                .AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems
            End With
            .Add(tbb)
            With tbb
                .TabIndex = 2
                .Location = New Point(95, 80)
                .Text = "textbox"
            End With

            .Add(b1)
            With b1
                .TabStop = False
                .Location = New Point(90, 130)
                .Text = "Nothing"
            End With
            .Add(b2)
            With b2
                .TabStop = False
                .Location = New Point(170, 130)
                .Text = "Exit"
                AddHandler b2.Click, AddressOf b2_Click
            End With
        End With
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Up Then
        e.Handled = True
        Me.SelectNextControl(Me.ActiveControl, False, True, True, True)
    End If

    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Down Then
        e.Handled = True
        Me.SelectNextControl(Me.ActiveControl, True, True, True, True)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub b2_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Me.Close()
End Sub
End Class
```

When you start this program pass several times through all controls with key down arrow. Then stop on combobox and type letter "a", then try to navigate again with key down arrow.

Comment: Just going to throw this out there... Can't you use `tab` to go through the combo boxes and the `arrow keys` to navigate within each combo box?

Comment: Yes I can, however, for tab I don't need any code. But I would like to keep navigation with arrows because of many reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Public Class Form1

    Private tb As New TextBox
    Private cbb As New ComboBox
    Private tbb As New TextBox
    Private b1 As New Button
    Private b2 As New Button

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        AddHandler cbb.PreviewKeyDown, AddressOf cbb_PreviewKeyDown
        AddHandler tb.PreviewKeyDown, AddressOf tb_PreviewKeyDown
        AddHandler tbb.PreviewKeyDown, AddressOf tbb_PreviewKeyDown

        Me.Size = New Size(350, 200)

        With tb
            .Parent = Me
            .TabIndex = 0
            .Location = New Point(95, 20)
            .Text = "This is"
        End With

        With cbb
            .Parent = Me
            .TabIndex = 1
            .Items.AddRange(New String() {"alabama", "africa", "australia", "grenland"})
            .Location = New Point(95, 50)
            .Text = "an Example"
            .DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown
            .AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend
            .AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems
        End With

        With tbb
            .Parent = Me
            .TabIndex = 2
            .Location = New Point(95, 80)
            .Text = "textbox"
        End With

        With b1
            .Parent = Me
            .TabStop = False
            .Location = New Point(90, 130)
            .Text = "Nothing"
        End With

        With b2
            .Parent = Me
            .TabStop = False
            .Location = New Point(170, 130)
            .Text = "Exit"
            AddHandler b2.Click, AddressOf b2_Click
        End With

    End Sub

    Private Sub tb_PreviewKeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PreviewKeyDownEventArgs)
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Up Then tbb.Focus()
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Down Then cbb.Focus()
    End Sub

    Private Sub cbb_PreviewKeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PreviewKeyDownEventArgs)
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Up Then
            cbb.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.None
            tb.Focus()
            cbb.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend
            If Not cbb.Items.Contains(cbb.Text) Then cbb.Text = ""
        End If
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Down Then
            cbb.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.None
            tbb.Focus()
            cbb.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend
            If Not cbb.Items.Contains(cbb.Text) Then cbb.Text = ""
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub tbb_PreviewKeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PreviewKeyDownEventArgs)
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Up Then cbb.Focus()
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Down Then tb.Focus()
    End Sub

    Private Sub b2_Click()
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

I modified your code. And now, it's working. :)

Comment: Hi Arvie :) Yes, your code work's. Not as expected but works. I can't still use it in my project. An IDEAL solution will be that combo "forget" searched string after loosing a focus but I cant find a way to achieve that.

Comment: Ok. I edited my code above. The combobox will now "forget" the searched string if it doesnt exist in the autocomplete items. If you prefer to forget the searched string everytime the combobox lost focus (I cant see any purpose for doing this) then just replace the "if condition" with cbb.Text = ""

Comment: Arvie, thank you for trying but still don't work as should. Problem more is here that I have several comboboxes and it will be a problem to add so much code to project. Key of all those problems is in forgetting an autocomplete value which can't be cleared with = "". You can navigate with up/down arrow in my original example until you press "a" in combobox. After that you can't. Most important question is: how to reset autocomplete to initial state after leaving combo so we can navigate again like we was on program start.